# Deserialize JSON with number objects in root

Tags: c#, json.net

I receive the following JSON:

```
{
"1": {
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": "",
    "projectId": 10000,
    "build": "",
    "totalExecutions": 1,
    "totalExecuted": 1,
    "environment": "",
    "description": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": -1,
                "statusName": "UNEXECUTED",
                "statusColor": "#A0A0A0",
                "statusDescription": "The test has not yet been executed."
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "statusKey": 1,
                "statusName": "PASS",
                "statusColor": "#75B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and passed successfully."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 2,
                "statusName": "FAIL",
                "statusColor": "#CC3300",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and failed."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 3,
                "statusName": "WIP",
                "statusColor": "#F2B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test execution is a work-in-progress."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 4,
                "statusName": "BLOCKED",
                "statusColor": "#6693B0",
                "statusDescription": "The test execution of this test was blocked for some reason."
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "expand": "executionSummaries",
    "versionId": 10000,
    "started": ""
},
"2":  {
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": "",
    "projectId": 10000,
    "build": "",
    "totalExecutions": 1,
    "totalExecuted": 1,
    "environment": "",
    "description": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": -1,
                "statusName": "UNEXECUTED",
                "statusColor": "#A0A0A0",
                "statusDescription": "The test has not yet been executed."
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "statusKey": 1,
                "statusName": "PASS",
                "statusColor": "#75B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and passed successfully."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 2,
                "statusName": "FAIL",
                "statusColor": "#CC3300",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and failed."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 3,
                "statusName": "WIP",
                "statusColor": "#F2B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test execution is a work-in-progress."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 4,
                "statusName": "BLOCKED",
                "statusColor": "#6693B0",
                "statusDescription": "The test execution of this test was blocked for some reason."
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "expand": "executionSummaries",
    "versionId": 10000,
    "started": ""
},
"3":  {
    "startDate": "",
    "endDate": "",
    "projectId": 10000,
    "build": "",
    "totalExecutions": 1,
    "totalExecuted": 1,
    "environment": "",
    "description": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "executionSummaries": {
        "executionSummary": [
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": -1,
                "statusName": "UNEXECUTED",
                "statusColor": "#A0A0A0",
                "statusDescription": "The test has not yet been executed."
            },
            {
                "count": 1,
                "statusKey": 1,
                "statusName": "PASS",
                "statusColor": "#75B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and passed successfully."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 2,
                "statusName": "FAIL",
                "statusColor": "#CC3300",
                "statusDescription": "Test was executed and failed."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 3,
                "statusName": "WIP",
                "statusColor": "#F2B000",
                "statusDescription": "Test execution is a work-in-progress."
            },
            {
                "count": 0,
                "statusKey": 4,
                "statusName": "BLOCKED",
                "statusColor": "#6693B0",
                "statusDescription": "The test execution of this test was blocked for some reason."
            }
        ]
    },
    "name": "Audit Test Cycle",
    "expand": "executionSummaries",
    "versionId": 10000,
    "started": ""
},
"recordsCount": 3}
```

}

One of the root object is recordcount, but the others are numbers. These numbers are important, so I can't loose them. The number is not incrementing with 1, it can be 8,5,2,4,6 or any other combination (but unique!).

I want to deserialize them into the following classes below, but don't know how to process the number.

```
public class Cycles //: Dictionary<string,Cycle>
{
    public Dictionary<string,Cycle> cycles { get; set; }
    public int recordsCount { get; set; } 
}


public class Cycle 
{
    public int totalExecutions { get; set; }
    public string endDate { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int totalExecuted { get; set; }
    public string started { get; set; }
    public string versionName { get; set; }
    public string expand { get; set; }
    public string projectKey { get; set; }
    public int versionId { get; set; }
    public string environment { get; set; }
    public string build { get; set; }
    public string createdBy { get; set; }
    public string ended { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string modifiedBy { get; set; }
    public int projectId { get; set; }
    public string createdByDisplay { get; set; }
    public string startDate { get; set; }
}
```

I know the JSON is not nice, but I can't change that. It's from a third party tool.

Normally I would just do

```
return _jsonDeserializer.Deserialize<Cycles>(response);
```

But that doesn't work.
So I tried not to "deserialize" it with:

```
Cycles result = new Cycles();
        JObject jsonOb = JObject.Parse(response.Content);
        result.recordsCount = jsonOb.Value<int>("recordsCount");
        jsonOb.Remove("recordsCount");
        var values = jsonOb.ToObject<Dictionary<string,Cycle>>();
        result.cycles = values;
```

I can get the "recordscount" data, but when trying to create the Dictionary I receive the error

```
error CS0119: 'Dictionary<string, Cycle>' is a type, which is not valid in the given contex
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Added my attempts to the original post.

Comment: The exact code you've given works for me - where are you getting the error?

Comment: Can you change the json to something like this : `"recordcount" : "1" {object}, "recordcount" : "2" {another object}` etc
It would be easier to process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we didn't have the `recordsCount` property in the JSON, it would be reasonably simple. As it is, I suspect the *simplest* approach is to using LINQ to JSON first, work out which values belong in the dictionary, and ask JSON.NET to convert each of those... but populate the top-level object yourself. (This is much like what you were already trying, by the looks of it.)

Here's an example that works with your sample data and classes:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var json = File.ReadAllText("test.json");
        var parsed = JObject.Parse(json);
        var cycles = new Cycles
        {
            cycles = parsed.Properties()
                .Where(p => int.TryParse(p.Name, out _))
                .ToDictionary(p => p.Name, p => p.Value.ToObject<Cycle>()),                  
            recordsCount = (int) parsed["recordsCount"]
        };
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", cycles.cycles.Keys));
    }
}
```

As an aside, I'd advise renaming all of your properties to idiomatic C# ones, and use `[JsonProperty]` to specify the name used in JSON.

Comment: @DavidH: I'm very glad it works - but as I noted before, the code in your question works for me as well. Still, at least you now have two ways to do it :)